How does this Haskell List Comprehension evaluate?
I'm learning Haskell and I came across this example in relation to list comprehensions:
[x | xs <- [[(3,4)],[(5,4),(3,2)]], (3,x) <- xs]
The answer given is:
[4,2].
Why isn't the answer [(3,4),(3,2)]?

Matching (3,x) against (3,4) gives x = 4. If you wanted (3,4), you should write [(3,x) | ...].

Um, I do not want (3,4). I just want an explanation for how the comprehension is processed. The text of the book I'm using does not provide any explanation for the given example.

I just gave one; is it unclear? Why do you expect x to be (3,4) in the first place?

Uh, no. I got it thanks! I'm just awaiting the "Accept answer" timeout. The syntax (3,x) <- xs is a little new to me though.

The left-hand side of <- is always a pattern match; in the case of xs <- ..., xs is an irrefutable pattern that simply assigns a value from the right-hand side to x.  (3, x) is a refutable pattern: not all values are 2-tuples with 3 and another value, but the ones that are have the other value assigned to x. (This is exactly the same kind of pattern matching used in function defintions, like f (3, x) = x, for example, causes f (3, 5) == 5.)

@kesarling In list comprehensions when using pat <- list, the elements of list are matched against pattern pat. Those that do not match are silently discarded. Those that match define the values of variables in pat. So (3,x) <- xs means "for all the elements of xs which are of the form (3,x) (for some x), ...". Note how x is bound to the second component of the pair, not to the whole pair.


Why isn't the answer [(3,4),(3,2)]?

The list comprehension:
[x | xs <- [[(3,4)],[(5,4),(3,2)]], (3,x) <- xs]

means that xs will be "assigned" every element of the list [[(3, 4)], [(5, 4), (3, 2)]], so it means in the first "iteration" xs is [(3,4)] and in the second it is [(5, 4), (3, 2)].
Then the same trick happens to the (3, x) <- xs part: it will enumerate over the items in xs, and try to match it with (3, x), so first the first "candidate" is (3, 4), and that matches, so x = 4 will yield a result; next there is (5, 4), but this does not work because the first item of the 2-tuple is 5, not 3. And finally an attempt is made with (3, 2), so then x is given x = 2.
The result of this is thus that we get a list with 4 and 2, so [4, 2].
